# #1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation in server Cpanel

Tags: database, cpanel, super, privileges

am facing this issue when i try to import database into my Cpanel
 and this error occured 
"#1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation"
Also, my database has 24 tables but affter this error only 20 tables imoorted.
Although database workes fine in other hosting and localhos

Here is the error:
Error
SQL query: Documentation

--

### -- Functions

CREATE DEFINER=`ato-qms-u-137073`@`%` FUNCTION `calculate_daily_rate` (`in_fleet_id` INT, `in_booking_days` INT, `in_booking_hours_per_day` INT) RETURNS FLOAT BEGIN

```
declare fare float;
declare min_booking_days int;
declare min_booking_hours_per_day int;
declare min_booking_days_amount float;
declare rate_per_day float;

SELECT 
    f.min_booking_days, f.min_booking_hours_per_day, f.min_booking_days_amount, f.rate_per_day 
    INTO min_booking_days, min_booking_hours_per_day, min_booking_days_amount, rate_per_day
    FROM fleet f
    WHERE f.id = in_fleet_id;

if(in_booking_hours_per_day < min_booking_hours_per_day) then
    return 0;
end if;

if(in_booking_days < min_booking_days) then
    return 0;
end if;

SET fare = min_booking_days_amount + (in_booking_days - min_booking_days) * rate_per_day;
return fare;
```

END

MySQL said: Documentation

## 1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation

Answer (score 0):

Error is because you do not have privileges to create trigger with this user `ato-qms-u-137073@%.`

Just remove this line from the code and it should work.

```
ato-qms-u-137073@%
```

Comment: I try by removing this line "ato-qms-u-137073@%
" but not worked it gives a lot of errors'

Comment: Here is the actual line, I tried also by adding the actual username
CREATE DEFINER=`airporttaxisonli_ato-qms`@`%` FUNCTION `calculate_daily_rate` (`in_fleet_id` INT, `in_booking_days` INT, `in_booking_hours_per_day` INT) RETURNS FLOAT BEGIN

Answer (score 0):

I think you solved it. But i'll laeve the answer here.
I edited database with notepad++, and deleted "Definer = your username @ local host".
Saved and tried again, for me it worked.